# Windows 10 Update error 0x8024402f

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Error message: There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x8024402f)

1. It is a fresh install (the very first operation after first login was a Update and it failed)
2. Microsoft Tech Support had remote access to my machine and tried everything (including Windows Update Troubleshooting and other tools). They reinstalled Windows and the problem persisted (then, I erased the HD with diskpart --> clean and reinstalled Windows from scratch, using a new MSDN ISO download)
3. I've manually installed the january 2017 cumulative patch (KB3213986) and installed (actual version: 1607 (OS Build 14393.693))
4. Tried every alternative (as delete the SoftwareDistribution folder, running some .bat with re-registration of some DLLs with regsvr32, winsocks reset, etc.)
5. There are no virus (already tested with Clam Anti Virus Portable, just to be sure)
6. No firewalls whatsoever (my machine is set to DMZ on internet router). Everything works just fine, except Windows Update.
7. Time and date are correct, using Microsoft's NTP server
8. I'm using Google DNS servers (8.8.8.8 e 8.8.4.4), with or without them, same error
9. I was a Windows Insider, but not anymore

I don't know what else I can do (except to wait for a Visual Studio for Linux and throw Windows in the trash) =\

Can anyone help me? =(

**UPDATE**: I've plugged in an old Wireless USB Adapter and, using Tethering on an Android with my 4G data, the update works normally.

So, the real question is: what is wrong with my normal internet connection that is preventing me from updating? What can I complain about with my ISP?

Comment: Can you make the following file available:
C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CBS.log
I guess it might be worth renaming the existing one, then force a retry. I assume it creates a new file with just the last attempt.

Comment: Availble here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/940dd2ba117e38920ec3c1eb420d90c3

Comment: Temporary solution: edit HOSTS file to make fe1.update.microsoft.com.akadns.net point to 134.170.115.62 (originally Google DNS resolves to 65.55.194.221)

Comment: Does following the steps here help:
http://www.tweaking.com/forums/index.php?topic=1864.0

Comment: Have you had this problem always or just recently.  Your solution seems odd if you still had the problem even if you were not using google dns

Comment: My last ISP was blocking EVERY port, so I switched ISPs recently. Never pay attention to Windows Update itself ('til some days ago, when I bought a new computer and had to reinstall Windows). Guess the problem has been up since my ISP (my notebook cannot update either).

Comment: For router problem: (1) Check for a firmware update, (2) Factory reset. Questions: (1) Can open the Windows Store? (2) Have you tried a clean install of a Windows 10 ISO version 1607 (not update to 1607)? (3) Did you run the Windows Update troubleshooter?  Note: The Windows Update detailed log might not help, but see [this article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/charlesa_us/2015/08/06/windows-10-windowsupdate-log-and-how-to-view-it-with-powershell-or-tracefmt-exe/), or alternatively see [this simpler method](http://www.jaapbrasser.com/windows-10-using-the-get-windowsupdatelog-cmdlet/).

Comment: Please answer my above comment. I further note that it's unlikely that your ISP is responsible because AFAIK Windows Update only requires the http(s) ports and there's no way that your ISP will block them or you wouldn't have Internet at all. Question: Does the problem happen when you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: 1) Firmware up to date (and, even so, I can't update my ISP hardware). 2) Again, it's ISP hardware, I can't (or shouldn't) touch it. 1) Yes. Windows Store works fine. 2) Yes, ISO 1607 (not update, only clean install). 3) Yes, all of them (and some of them I didn't know before)

Comment: (1) Remains to check Windows Update when booting in Safe mode. Before that, in Settings > Update & Security > Advanced options, set "Notify to schedule restart" and uncheck all else and reboot. (2) Try this [Microsoft troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors). (3) Download & install [.NET 4.6.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53344). (4) This error means your computer can’t connect with Microsoft Update server - ask your ISP Support if they were crazy enough to block the servers (I really don't believe in that).

Comment: Do a darn network trace with Wireshark or an equivalent tool, trace when it does not work through ISP and save the capture, and then run it from your wifi mobile hot spot or whatever when it does work and save that capture. Now start sifting through and find differences, apply filters, etc. stop guessing what the problem is and look at the network packets and determine what the problem really is if it's network related.  Use your ISP DNS rather than Google's too and only ONE network adapter connected and retry with all but one network adapter enabled.

Comment: Read over this link too: http://blog.mikewconsulting.com/tag/httpsupport-microsoft-comkb836941/ and I read on some post when searching that it may be related to Microsoft Office so keep Google searching the error since you exhausted all other suggestions below... Assuming you did attempt all suggestions from all comments and answer... Too much to read but you're probably overlooking something simple. One suggestion is to reach out to your ISP since you confirmed it's an issue with their network, ask them and/or trace and then ask them with your proof...

Comment: did you call your ISP to tell them about the problem ? from what I can read in your post including most of the comments here it sounds like a network configuration problem, your ISP, router, your wireless or network connection. nothing else other than those I mentionned ? 

if its your ISP then this is seriously strange as they shouldn't block that kind of update or behavior...I know ISP block certain ports like port 80 to prevent people making servers and such but windows update...not to my knowledge

Answer (score 2):

Error `0x8024402F` means `WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS`:

> // MessageId: WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS 
>   // 
>   // MessageText: 
>   //
>   // External cab file processing completed with some errors. 
>   // #define **WU_E_PT_ECP_SUCCEEDED_WITH_ERRORS** _HRESULT_TYPEDEF_(**0x8024402F**L)

Stop the Windows Update service, delete the content of the folder `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download`. Also [exclude this folder from your Anti Virus suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939908%28WS.10%29.aspx#av).

Now try again to update Windows 10.

Comment: As I said in 4) and 5), it is useless.

Comment: I have no idea why your ISP corrupts the CABs. Normally my steps fix the issue because they happen mostly only on client side.

Answer (score 2):

```
>what is wrong with my normal internet connection that is preventing me from updating?
```

Your ISP (or someone upstream) surely is caching MS updates (in order to avoid downloading million times the same file) and some of them got corrupted...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the exact cause is, but the following is a possible workaround: click on Advanced Options under Windows Update and deselect "Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows."

Answer (score 1):

If it appears your ISP is caching updates and possibly causing this problem, one solution would be to use a VPN connection to download the updates.

While I cannot suggest a VPN option, careful Google research should indicate trustworthy ones to use which would offer a free trial period or allow you to pay for only one month of service which should be less than $10 USD.

Using a VPN would bypass your ISP and their caching entirely, allowing you to get a good copy of the update files.

If the issue persists even after using a VPN, then it would not be the fault of the ISP.

Answer (score 0):

I understand in the original question that the OP's computer is in a DMZ and that the firewall should not be the issue.  However, my source of this chronic problem was a Cisco SMB router's firewall setting for [blocking/filtering ActiveX controls](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10972/fix-windows-update-errors-by-letting-activex-traffic-through/). Simply disabling that feature resolved the issue.

Comment: Windows 10 won't use ActiveX anymore for Windows Update.

Comment: Nevertheless, the Cisco SMB router/firewall setting labeled (by Cisco) as blocking "ActiveX" was the direct cause of my `0x8024402f` error in Win10.  I can reproduce this at will by changing that one setting on the router.